# How to read an argument in from command line into a double?

Tags: c

This program is first forked then run by execlp, it's calling program passes in two numbers, a power and a base.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid = getpid();
    printf("Calculator Process[%d]: started\n",pid);
    double base, power;
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&base);
    sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&power);
    double number = pow(base,power);
    printf("Calculator Process[%d]: %d ^^ %d == %d\n",pid,base,power,number);
    printf("Calculator Process[%d]: exiting\n",pid);
    return 1;
}
```

Lets say I pass into it base 3, power 5. This is what I get:

```
base = 4263 -- this also happens to be the PID. 
power = -1 
raised to power: 714477568
```

Calling line:

```
execlp("./calculator","./calculator",argv[1],argv[2],(char*)0);
```

When I print the argvs, I get their value (as a char*, but casting fails).

Any ideas why I can't get the values to be correctly read in?

Comment: Read [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html): using `"%d"` requires a (pointer to) int; for a (pointer to) double you need `"%lf"`.

Comment: Think about using `strtod()` instead of `sscanf()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either read double:

```
double base, power;
sscanf(argv[1],"%lf",&base);
sscanf(argv[2],"%lf",&power);
```

Or scan into integers:

```
int base, power;
sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&base);
sscanf(argv[2],"%d",&power);
```

Comment: The proper treatment for a simple typo in code is to fix it, not downvote it.

Comment: @Andy: downvoting **with a comment** makes the OP fix it and avoids a fabricated history of "edited by"s :) -- I'd edit after 5 minutes. (Note that I removed the comment (and the downvote) after the ninja edit)

Comment: consider using sscanf_s()

Answer (score 0):

A quick adjustment of your code should do it:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int pid = getpid();
    printf("Calculator Process[%d]: started\n",pid);
    double base, power;
    base = atof(argv[1]);
    power = atof(argv[2]);
    double number = pow(base,power);
    printf("Calculator Process[%d]: %f ^^ %f == %f\n",pid,base,power,number);
    printf("Calculator Process[%d]: exiting\n",pid);
    return 1;
```

}

1. For converting a char array to a digit you can use `atof()`
2. Don't forget to update the printf to a double `%f` or they won't display right in your output!

Comment: -1: for printing a double the format is `"%f"` (remember that float values are automatically converted to type double and the inside of `printf` never ever sees a value of type float). Use `"%lf"` in printf for values of type `long double` (C99).

Comment: @pmg - good catch, I was thinking about `scanf()`. Updated. Thanks.